# A big cannon to match a ballistic missile?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, estimation

During the last years of WW2 the Germans used ballistic missiles V-2 (with payload mass ~1,000 kg) to bombard London, from a distance about 300 km away. Suppose the British could respond by building a cannon of a very large size, to shoot back conventional projectiles. Would this be realistic? Neglecting the air, the maximum projectile range (shot at 45 degrees to the horizon) is $R=V^2/g$, where $V$ is the projectile muzzle velocity. For $R$=300,000 m and $g$=10 m$^2$/s one needs $V$=1,700 m/s. This is on the high side but within the reach for conventional rifles and cannons. Does the presence of the Earth atmosphere make it practically impossible to shoot projectiles at such large distances? Since the air resistance should scale with the projectile cross-section, $F \sim \rho V^2 A$, can a very long and thin hypersonic projectile travel easily through the atmosphere?

Comment: Have you tried just doing the basic kinematics of this?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos The basic kinematics, without considering the atmosphere, would just say that the projectile needs to be at the speed ~1 km/s to travel ~100 km in the Earth gravity. Without the atmosphere a cannon is probably much more efficient than a rocket in terms of energy needed. A cannon allows "pushing" against the Earth which has infinite mass so most of the fuel energy goes into the projectile while a rocket has to push against its exhaust, and a large fraction of fuel energy will be lost as the kinetic energy of the exhaust.

Comment: No, not really. Instead of asking here a absolutely technological question, better google for things like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwerer_Gustav This is WWII state of art, with a max range of about 47 km. 28 cam railway guns fired about 100 km, but the accuracy was very bad.

Answer (score 6):

The V2 reached a height of 80 km at the peak of its approximately parabolic trajectory. To reach such altitude (ignoring friction) requires a supersonic take-off speed of

$$V = \sqrt{\frac{gh}{2}}=630 m/s$$

That's a tough nut to crack with conventional ballistics, although regular firearms have muzzle velocities that are up there - the Swift reaches 1200 m/s, but it's a 0.22 (4.5 mm) caliber... as the bullet gets larger, the force scales with the cross-sectional area, but the mass with the volume - so it's a problem of scale.

The kinetic energy needed is $\frac12 m v^2$ = 200 MJ. If your 1000 kg object was a sphere with an average density of 2,500 kg/m$^3$, then the radius would be 0.45 m and the surface area 0.63 m$^2$. Using the equations given at http://closefocusresearch.com/calculating-barrel-pressure-and-projectile-velocity-gun-systems we can compute (with the spreadsheet linked there) the parameters of a gun that can send a 1000 kg projectile out of the barrel at a velocity of 630 m/s: With a mean barrel pressure of 2000 atm, and a barrel length of 4.5 m, this calculates a muzzle velocity of 630 m/s. However, the calculation does assume that the pressure is maintained while the projectile is expelled. This may be true for a short barrel gun with a large charge, but it's unrealistic for such a large gun.

To compare: "Big Bertha" was able to fire a 820 kg missile over 12.5 km with a muzzle velocity of 400 m/s - and its barrel was almost 6 m long and 41.5 cm diameter. Of course missiles are typically not cannonball shaped - their air resistance would be much too great, so they are made more bullet-shaped. This shape makes them fly further, but it also means that more pressure (or a longer barrel) is required to get the needed velocity.

One big concern would be the acceleration in the barrel - it is hard to see how you could prevent detonation of the charge with the kind of explosive force you would need. Slightly gentler acceleration with a rocket motor was definitely the right way to go.

Incidentally, the drag force on such a large projectile would be very considerable.  Using

$$F = \frac12 \rho v^2 A C_D$$

we get (with a $C_D \approx 0.5$) $F = 80 kN$, so it would decelerate rather quickly. Another reason why it is better to get some altitude before really getting up to speed (the V-2 accelerated for about 60 seconds, reaching 10km altitude where the density of air is considerably lower (about 0.4x of the density at sea level), and finally dropping straight down onto the target. The density of the projectile (and thus its size) is mostly determined by the density of the payload - considerably less than the density of an iron or lead cannonball, but more destructive on arrival.

On the whole, the prospect of a non-rocket based "V-2 me-too" based on technology available in 1944 seems dim. Which is why Bomber Command did what it did.

And incidentally, more people died in the production of the V-2 than in the deployment (mostly prisoners) - so it was really a spectacularly unsuccessful weapon, although it set off the entire ballistic arms race.

One other tidbit: the best defense that the British found against the increasingly accurate V-2 was to falsely report that the rockets were hitting targets to the West of London. The Nazis, confused, "recalibrated" their systems and ended up shooting short - hitting sparsely populated areas to the East of London (Kent). Clever chaps, those Brits.

Comment: You read too much propaganda.

Comment: Just realized my velocity calculations are off by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ as you need to fire this hypothetical gun at 45°, not straight up. It makes the problem even bigger - barrel needs to be a lot (2x?) longer.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about something like the Kaiser Wilhelm Gun used on Paris in WWI, but bigger.

Problem with big guns is they reach a point where rockets are better in almost every respect. Accelerating a 1000kg projectile inside a barrel to speeds where it can reach a target 300km away would be nearly impossible. Missiles start slow and do most of their acceleration higher up where the air is thinner. Guns will lose a lot of speed in the first kilometers of climb, so you need that much more energy at the beginning. Which means a bigger gun and a bigger charge. And eventually the projectile melts or explodes before it leaves the barrel.

Comment: All good arguments, still some people these days are considering non-rocket space launch, e.g., with electromagnetic guns, also check out the HARP and SHARP projects sponsored by US government not too long ago. According to online resources, the project HARP in 1966 put a 180 kg projectile to impressive 180 km altitude, setting a record that is still standing.